# Converting C-style series of casts on AfxGetMainWnd from VC6/MFC6 to operate in modern MFC version (VC++2008 and later)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

An application I'm porting from Visual C++ 6.0 to the MFC version in VC++2008, does a lot of get-`AfxGetMainWnd()`-and-do-C-Style-casts on it like this:

```
  CUserInterfaceDoc *m_pDoc = (CUserInterfaceDoc*)((CFrameWnd *)AfxGetMainWnd())
                            ->GetActiveDocument();
```

When I try the steps above, simply converting to `dynamic_cast<>`, I find that the Main Window is no longer accessible via casting-to-a-`CUserInterfaceDoc` in my program.  I think that perhaps MFC had abused casts in VC++ 6, or that the compiler did some magic.

Rewriting the above to use dynamic casts would go like this, and it ends up with a nil pointer, which trips the assert() conditions I wrote here, as I want it to:

```
CUserInterfaceDoc *m_pDoc;
CWnd * mainWnd = AfxGetMainWnd();
assert(mainWnd);
CFrameWnd *frmWnd = dynamic_cast<CFrameWnd *> (mainWnd);
assert(frmWnd);
m_pDoc = dynamic_cast<CUserInterfaceDoc *> (frmWnd);
assert(m_pDoc);
```

I'm assuming that everybody who has done this before will be able to say "Yeah, of course, they changed that casting behaviour...." but I can't find the documentation for it.

Where possible I'm changing my C++ classes to have a member variable (field) where I store
links to things that it was formerly finding by walking down from the "more or less global" `AfxMainWnd()`.

It would help me to know what changed though, so I can understand what's going on above.

`CUserInterfaceDoc` is my application's MFC C++ Document class, it is a COleServerDoc which used to be "findable" at runtime with the gross C-style cast at the top.

The above cast still compiles in modern C++ but it's broken, probably due to the fact that the old VC++ 6 compiler did some kind of internal 'magic' with C-style casts that was against the ISO C++ standards. (That's purely a guess on my part).

My question is in two parts:

1. What's the usual way to get at the CurrentDocument  (CFrameWnd::CurrentDocument) from another class that currently has no reference to the main CFrameWnd and had been using the hack I show at the top of this question?
2. What changed between the non-ISO-compliant VC++ 6 and the more-or-less ISO-compliant later C++ versions that would change the behaviour of the cast expressions above, or did the breakage occur due to MFC internal architecture changes?

My code change:

```
CUserInterfaceDoc * CMyBrowser::GetUserInterfaceDoc()
{
    CUserInterfaceDoc *m_pDoc;
    // formerly did this, which works in VC++6 and doesn't work anymore:
    //m_pDoc = (CUserInterfaceDoc*)((CFrameWnd *)AfxGetMainWnd())->GetActiveDocument();
    assert(m_pMainFrm);
    m_pDoc = dynamic_cast<CUserInterfaceDoc *> ( m_pMainFrm->GetActiveDocument() );
    assert(m_pDoc);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first rewrite:

```
CUserInterfaceDoc *m_pDoc;
CWnd * mainWnd = AfxGetMainWnd();
assert(mainWnd);
CFrameWnd *frmWnd = dynamic_cast<CFrameWnd *> (mainWnd);
assert(frmWnd);
m_pDoc = dynamic_cast<CUserInterfaceDoc *> (frmWnd);
assert(m_pDoc);
```

... you simply missed the GetActiveDocument() call which was there in the C-Style cast. So it should work like this:

```
CUserInterfaceDoc *m_pDoc;
CWnd * mainWnd = AfxGetMainWnd();
assert(mainWnd);
CFrameWnd *frmWnd = dynamic_cast<CFrameWnd *> (mainWnd);
assert(frmWnd);    
m_pDoc = dynamic_cast<CUserInterfaceDoc *> (frmWnd->GetActiveDocument());
assert(m_pDoc);
```

DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST is soo oldschool and actually no longer required if you enable RTTI (which is on by default).
See also: [MFC DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030525/mfc-dynamic-downcast-vs-dynamic-cast/34549647)

Comment: Accepted this answer as the one from 2012 does seem pretty dated, and others may come along and find this better advice.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MFC, you might as well just bite the bullet and use DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST which is an MFC defined macro for casting that's basically equivalent to dynamic_cast.

```
CFrameWnd* pFrm = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CFrameWnd, AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd);

m_pDoc = DYNAMIC_CAST(CUserInterfaceDoc, m_pMainFrm->GetActiveDocument());
```

Comment: Is this usage still considered "acceptable" or is the above considered an MFC mis-feature?

Comment: It's how you are supposed to do it if you're using MFC.  It takes advantage of the run time type information inherent in the MFC framework for classes derived from CObject.

Comment: It seems more likely these days that the compiler RTTI is the better and safer way to operate.

Comment: I'll stick with the way that is still followed in the MFC source code.