# MFC DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST vs. dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, casting, mfc

What is the difference between `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` from MFC library and standard C++ `dynamic_cast` operator? Can I use safety `dynamic_cast` instead of `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` for MFC objects?

When my classes contain `DECLARE_DYNAMIC` and `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC` macros, can I use `dynamic_cast` operator or I must use `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` macro for this type of objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is DECLARE\_DYNAMIC & IMPLEMENT\_DYNAMIC nessary for DYNAMIC\_DOWNCAST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318993/why-is-declare-dynamic-implement-dynamic-nessary-for-dynamic-downcast)

Comment: @RichardCritten Indicated post does not contain answer for my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the difference between DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST from MFC library and standard C++ dynamic_cast operator?

DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST and dynamic_cast achieve the same thing, information about an object's data type at runtime, through different mechanisms. DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST works through the use of a set of macros to declare and implement methods used to get the object's class information. dynamic_cast achieves the same thing through the use of Run-Time Type Information, which is implemented by the compiler.

> Can I use safety dynamic_cast instead of DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST for MFC objects?
>   When my classes contain DECLARE_DYNAMIC and IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC macros, can I use dynamic_cast operator or I must use DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST macro for this type of objects?

The use of dynamic_cast is allowed if you compile using RTTI and have at least one virtual method.
DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST implements a bunch of virtual methods so you only have to check if your compiler supports RTTI and that it is turned on.